# Angular js - calling data-modal-target from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular and have a question about modal. In my html I have am using data-modal-target like this

```
          <li>
            <button data-modal-target='#delete-connection' ng-click="deleteConnection(cloudconnection.id)">Delete Connection</button>
          </li>
```

I have a div with id delete-connection defined in my html which has contents of modal dialog like OK/Cancel. The above code works just fine and I see a modal dialog when button is clicked.

But now I want to show this modal dialog from my controller.  When button is clicked I want to call a method in the controller, do some processing there and then show the modal dialog conditionally.  What's the easiest way to show that modal dialog?  One way that I have seen in other answers is to define its own controller with template file etc.  I am wondering if I can just use my existing div for modal dialog and somehow enable it from my controller.  I tried something like -

$('#delete-connection').modal();

But I get a reference error stating $ is not defined.

Can someone suggest what I should do here?

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify instead of using data-modal-target I added "$('#delete-connection').modal()" shown above in my deleteConnection method.  But that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you havn't included jquery refernce.

If you need to do angular way try using angular-ui

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal

Answer (score 0):

This error can only be caused by one of following:

1. JavaScript file is not being properly loaded into your page
2. You have a botched version of jQuery. This could happen because someone edited the core file, or a plugin may have overwritten the $ variable.
3. You have JavaScript running before the page is fully loaded, and as such, before jQuery is fully loaded.

Make sure all javascript code is being run inside a code block such as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //your code here
});
```

This will ensure that your code is being loaded after jQuery has been initialized.
One final thing to check is to make sure that you are not loading any plugins before you load jQuery. Plugins extend the "$" object, so if you load a plugin before loading jQuery core, then you'll get the error you described.